# How to get the Data type of items in an empty Bindingsource?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, bindingsource

I have a bindingsource bound to an entity.

When the bindingsource has at least one element , I can get the items type with :

```
MyBindingSource.Current.GetType
```

But how can I do in the case when bindingsource is empty ?

Thank you !

**Update**

I have used :

```
MyBindingSource.GetItemProperties(Nothing)(0).ComponentType
```

but even this method doesn't work when bindingsource has no items.

Comment: No you can't. unless the bindingsource is `Nothing`, not empty

Comment: I mean when the bindingsource has no items.

Comment: Can you guarantee that your `BindingSource` will be bound to an object that implements `IList(Of T)`?  If so then you can use Reflection to determine the type of `T`.

Comment: My bindingsource is bound to an entity  ( entity framework 6)

Comment: "bound to an entity". Please elaborate. + What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Gert : why you have removed your response ? It's not possible to modify to make it work ?

Comment: By "doesn;t work" I mean that an error is produced because there are no items in bindingsource.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is working on a bindingsource that has no items :

```
MyBindingSource.DataSource.UnderLyingSystemType.Name
```